# Exclude a specific category link from archive / front page

Tags: archives, categories

I create posts that are used just to create an index item to show an existing post has been updated. The post I create 301 redirects to the updated post. I add these index posts to the category 'Update' and this excludes the posts from the previous and next post links via a plugin (I couldn't find any other way).

Problem is on the front page and archive pages the category each post is included in is displayed. I would like to exclude 'Update' category from these links as it is just for admin purposes.

Can I add something to my functions.php file which will prevent all links to the 'Update' category archive page being displayed?

Appreciate any guidance and apologies if this is covered already under a different term / search. I have looked.

Comment: You create posts that do nothing but redirect to other posts? Why not just sort by last updated?

Comment: That's an option I guess (that I had never considered) but I can give the 'new' post a unique title and it stays in my index. So I upload a tutorial and post it. 6 weeks later my tutorial gets featured somewhere. I update the tutorial post with an anchor linked section and create a new post titled 'tutorial x featured by...' with a 301 redirect to the anchor linked section of the original post. Seems to work a treat with this one issue.

Comment: Seems kinda messy to me, but its your site.

Comment: Works really well for me but its a personal blog so maybe not what a commercial blogger would do :)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you are using [`get_categories`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_categories) to print the category links, there is an `exclude` parameter. You need to use `ID`s, so you will need to convert the slug with [`get_term_by`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_term_by)

```
$cid = get_term_by('slug','update','category');
// var_dump($cid);
get_categories(
  array(
    'exclude' => $cid->term_id
  )
);
```

Comment: Great thank you. Can this be turned into a function to include in functions.php or do I need to edit template files?

Comment: It can certainly be turned into a function but I doubt there is a hook that you can use to avoid editing theme templates. That really depends on where you want the code _exactly_, and I don't know that.

Comment: Thank you @s_ha_dum you've been more helpful than I could ask. I would need the code to kick in on my home page (which is a static page) and also I think probably all my archive templates because they all show the category with link in the post detail. This is my home page http://skipology.com (see News and App workflow) and this is one example of my category archives http://skipology.com/category/news/ - if you can provide no further guidance then no problem, I'm very grateful for your help.

Comment: What you are asking now depends on the theme and is almost certainly a template edit. The only reliable and relevant hooks are probably `the_content` and `the_excerpt` if you want to insert the links into the post body.

Comment: Thank you very much once again. I guess it's a step too far for me. I'll just have to leave it visible for now. I think I saw a plugin somewehere which may handle it so will research that route instead. Really grateful for your help.